# Azure Logic App Outlook Connector “Send Email with Options”

Tags: outlook, azure-logic-apps, o365-flow

I am trying to create a flow in Logic app which will send a outage email to bunch of recipient. Now here I have to add a trigger which will get the user details from PostgreSQL stored in variable. In email session I will call this variable in To session.

Connect PostgreSQL
Get User details
Stored in Variable
calling the variable in Outlook session

Please need your help

Answer (score 0):

Now `PostgreSQL` connector available in logic app. If you use PostgreSQL connector in a logic app you need to create a **gateway**. That gateway installation, which appears in the list only when these **conditions** are met:

- The gateway installation uses the **same region** as the gateway resource that you want to create.
- The gateway installation **isn't linked to another Azure gateway resource**.
- The gateway installation is linked to the **same Azure account** that you're using to create the gateway resource.
- Your Azure account belongs to a single [Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant or directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis#terminology) and is the same account that you used for the gateway installation.

[image]

If it is possible to create a gateway you can use PostgreSQL Connector. Otherwise, you can use below method

You can use **Azure function** to connect `PostgreSQL` and get data from `PostgreSQL` using azure function.

Try to add the **azure function** in logic app ([Check here for azure function call from logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions)  ).

Create a Custom API Connector ( [logic-apps-create-api-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app) ) & a Custom Logic App Connector ([custom-connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/custom-connector-overview) )

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5589a7939/15997690)

Comment: Thanks for the response. let me try and get back to you if any help needed.